# (chartjs migration v2 -> v3/4) a point outside the graph is not connected by a line

Tags: chart.js, chartjs-plugin-zoom

I migrated from version 2 to 4. The graph does not draw lines to points that are outside the graph. I use the plugin chartjs-plugin-zoom.

I am using spanGaps for to link points. But points outside the graph does not work.

you see old version and new version on video - https://cloud.mail.ru/public/pxTm/6sb3fxmnt

I could not search answer for it issue.

version 2 - is working

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hammerjs@2.0.8"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-zoom@0.7.7"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>

        <script>
            const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

            new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange', 'Red2', 'Blue2', 'Yellow2', 'Green2', 'Purple2', 'Orange2', 'Red3', 'Blue3', 'Yellow3', 'Green3', 'Purple3', 'Orange3', 'Red4', 'Blue4', 'Yellow4', 'Green4', 'Purple4', 'Orange4', 'Red5', 'Blue5', 'Yellow5', 'Green5', 'Purple5', 'Orange5', 'Red6', 'Blue6', 'Yellow6', 'Green6', 'Purple6', 'Orange6', 'Red7', 'Blue7', 'Yellow7', 'Green7', 'Purple7', 'Orange7'],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: '# of Votes',
                        data: [12, 19, 3, null, 2, 3, 12, 19, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 2, 3, 12, 19, 3, null, 2, 3, 12, null, 3, 5, 2, 3, 12, null, 3, 5, 2, 3, 12, null, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    spanGaps: true,
                    elements: {
                        line: {
                            tension: 0.3,
                            fill: false,
                        }
                    },
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            beginAtZero: true,
                            ticks: {
                                min: 0,
                                max: 20
                            }
                        }],
                        xAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                min: 'Yellow3',
                                max: 'Orange7'
                            }
                        }]
                    },
                    plugins: {
                        zoom: {
                            pan: {
                                enabled: true,
                                mode: 'x',
                                speed: 5
                            },
                            zoom: {
                                enabled: true,
                                mode: 'x',
                                scaleMode: 'x',
                                wheel: {
                                    enabled: true
                                },
                                sensitivity: 0.1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

version 4 (3 too) - is not working

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hammerjs@2.0.8"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-zoom/2.0.1/chartjs-plugin-zoom.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>

        <script>
            const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

            new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange', 'Red2', 'Blue2', 'Yellow2', 'Green2', 'Purple2', 'Orange2', 'Red3', 'Blue3', 'Yellow3', 'Green3', 'Purple3', 'Orange3', 'Red4', 'Blue4', 'Yellow4', 'Green4', 'Purple4', 'Orange4', 'Red5', 'Blue5', 'Yellow5', 'Green5', 'Purple5', 'Orange5', 'Red6', 'Blue6', 'Yellow6', 'Green6', 'Purple6', 'Orange6', 'Red7', 'Blue7', 'Yellow7', 'Green7', 'Purple7', 'Orange7'],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: '# of Votes',
                        data: [12, 19, 3, null, 2, 3, 12, 19, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 2, 3, 12, 19, 3, null, 2, 3, 12, null, 3, 5, 2, 3, 12, null, 3, 5, 2, 3, 12, null, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    spanGaps: true,
                    elements: {
                        line: {
                            tension: 0.3,
                        }
                    },
                    scales: {
                        y: {
                            beginAtZero: true,
                            min: 0,
                            max: 20
                        },
                        x: {
                            // type: 'linear',
                            min: 'Yellow3',
                            max: 'Orange7'
                        }
                    },
                    plugins: {
                        zoom: {
                            pan: {
                                enabled: true,
                                mode: 'x',
                                speed: 5
                            },
                            zoom: {
                                enabled: true,
                                mode: 'x',
                                scaleMode: 'x',
                                wheel: {
                                    enabled: true
                                },
                                sensitivity: 0.1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also you can see curve line is shaking after chart moving (new version chartjs)